# Display recent wordpress posts in a same static page form multiple wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way to Display recent wordpress posts in a same static page form multiple wordpress site which is hosted under same domian, under sub directories. Please let me know if there is a way to do this, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

wpmudev.org has a "[post indexer](http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/post-indexer/)" plugin that grabs all the posts, sitewide, across a multisite. You could then display them however you want.

Comment: it's two separate wordpress installation under same domain, I am using
the following code to grab from one but cant do the same for other as it over writes the header

<?php require_once('wp-blog-header.php'); ?>